# How to split up complex conditions and keep short circuit evaluation?

Tags: java

Sometimes conditions can become quite complex, so for readability I usually split them up and give each component a meaningful name. This defeats short-circuit evaluation however, which can pose a problem. I came up with a wrapper approach, but it is way too verbose in my opinion.

Can anybody come up with a neat solution for this?

See code below for examples of what I mean:

```
public class BooleanEvaluator {

    // problem: complex boolean expression, hard to read
    public static void main1(String[] args) {

        if (args != null && args.length == 2 && !args[0].equals(args[1])) {
            System.out.println("Args are ok");
        }
    }

    // solution: simplified by splitting up and using meaningful names
    // problem: no short circuit evaluation
    public static void main2(String[] args) {

        boolean argsNotNull = args != null;
        boolean argsLengthOk = args.length == 2;
        boolean argsAreNotEqual = !args[0].equals(args[1]);

        if (argsNotNull && argsLengthOk && argsAreNotEqual) {
            System.out.println("Args are ok");
        }
    }

    // solution: wrappers to delay the evaluation 
    // problem: verbose
    public static void main3(final String[] args) {

        abstract class BooleanExpression {
            abstract boolean eval();
        }

        BooleanExpression argsNotNull = new BooleanExpression() {
            boolean eval() {
                return args != null;
            }
        };

        BooleanExpression argsLengthIsOk = new BooleanExpression() {
            boolean eval() {
                return args.length == 2;
            }
        };

        BooleanExpression argsAreNotEqual = new BooleanExpression() {
            boolean eval() {
                return !args[0].equals(args[1]);
            }
        };

        if (argsNotNull.eval() && argsLengthIsOk.eval() && argsAreNotEqual.eval()) {
            System.out.println("Args are ok");
        }
    }
}
```

**Response to answers:**

Thanks for all your ideas! The following alternatives were submitted so far:

- Break lines and add comments
- Leave as is
- Extract methods
- Early returns
- Nested / Split up if's

**Break lines and add comments:**

Just adding linebreaks within a condition gets undone by the code formatter in Eclipse (ctrl+shift+f). Inline comments helps with this, but leaves little space on each line and can result in ugly wrapping. In simple cases this might be enough however.

**Leave as is:**

The example condition I gave is quite simplistic, so you might not need to address readability issues in this case. I was thinking of situations where the condition is much more complex, for example:

```
private boolean targetFound(String target, List<String> items,
        int position, int min, int max) {

    return ((position >= min && position < max && ((position % 2 == 0 && items
            .get(position).equals(target)) || (position % 2 == 1)
            && position > min && items.get(position - 1).equals(target)))
            || (position < min && items.get(0).equals(target)) || (position >= max && items
            .get(items.size() - 1).equals(target)));
}
```

I would not recommend leaving this as it is.

**Extract methods:**

I considered extracting methods, as was suggested in several answers. The disadvantage of that is that these methods typically have a very low granularity and may not be very meaningful by themselves, so it can clutter your class, for example:

```
private static boolean lengthOK(String[] args) {
    return args.length == 2;
}
```

This would not really deserve to be a separate method at class level. Also you have to pass all the relevant arguments to each method. If you create a separate class purely for evaluating a very complex condition then this might be an ok solution IMO.

What I tried to achieve with the BooleanExpression approach is that the logic remains local. Notice that even the declaration of BooleanExpression is local (I don't think I've ever come across a use-case for a local class declaration before!).

**Early returns:**

The early returns solution seems adequate, even though I don't favor the idiom. An alternative notation:

```
public static boolean areArgsOk(String[] args) {

    check_args: {
        if (args == null) {
            break check_args;
        }
        if (args.length != 2) {
            break check_args;
        }
        if (args[0].equals(args[1])) {
            break check_args;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I realize most people hate labels and breaks, and this style might be too uncommon to be considered readable.

**Nested/split up if's:**

It allows the introduction of meaningful names in combination with optimized evaluation. A drawback is the complex tree of conditional statements that can ensue

**Showdown**

So to see which approach I utlimately favor, I applied several of the suggested solutions to the complex targetFound example presented above. Here are my results:

**nested / split if's, with meaningful names**
very verbose, meaningful names don't really help the readability here

```
private boolean targetFound1(String target, List<String> items,
        int position, int min, int max) {

    boolean result;
    boolean inWindow = position >= min && position < max;
    if (inWindow) {

        boolean foundInEvenPosition = position % 2 == 0
                && items.get(position).equals(target);
        if (foundInEvenPosition) {
            result = true;
        } else {
            boolean foundInOddPosition = (position % 2 == 1)
                    && position > min
                    && items.get(position - 1).equals(target);
            result = foundInOddPosition;
        }
    } else {
        boolean beforeWindow = position < min;
        if (beforeWindow) {

            boolean matchesFirstItem = items.get(0).equals(target);
            result = matchesFirstItem;
        } else {

            boolean afterWindow = position >= max;
            if (afterWindow) {

                boolean matchesLastItem = items.get(items.size() - 1)
                        .equals(target);
                result = matchesLastItem;
            } else {
                result = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**nested / split if's, with comments**
less verbose, but still hard to read and easy to create bugs

```
private boolean targetFound2(String target, List<String> items,
        int position, int min, int max) {

    boolean result;
    if ((position >= min && position < max)) { // in window

        if ((position % 2 == 0 && items.get(position).equals(target))) {
            // even position
            result = true;
        } else { // odd position
            result = ((position % 2 == 1) && position > min && items.get(
                    position - 1).equals(target));
        }
    } else if ((position < min)) { // before window
        result = items.get(0).equals(target);
    } else if ((position >= max)) { // after window
        result = items.get(items.size() - 1).equals(target);
    } else {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**early returns**
even more compact, but the conditional tree remains just as complex

```
private boolean targetFound3(String target, List<String> items,
        int position, int min, int max) {

    if ((position >= min && position < max)) { // in window

        if ((position % 2 == 0 && items.get(position).equals(target))) {
            return true; // even position
        } else {
            return (position % 2 == 1) && position > min && items.get(
                    position - 1).equals(target); // odd position
        }
    } else if ((position < min)) { // before window
        return items.get(0).equals(target);
    } else if ((position >= max)) { // after window
        return items.get(items.size() - 1).equals(target);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**extracted methods**
results in nonsensical methods in your class
the parameter passing is annoying

```
private boolean targetFound4(String target, List<String> items,
        int position, int min, int max) {

    return (foundInWindow(target, items, position, min, max)
            || foundBefore(target, items, position, min) || foundAfter(
            target, items, position, max));
}

private boolean foundAfter(String target, List<String> items, int position,
        int max) {
    return (position >= max && items.get(items.size() - 1).equals(target));
}

private boolean foundBefore(String target, List<String> items,
        int position, int min) {
    return (position < min && items.get(0).equals(target));
}

private boolean foundInWindow(String target, List<String> items,
        int position, int min, int max) {
    return (position >= min && position < max && ((position % 2 == 0 && items
            .get(position).equals(target)) || (position % 2 == 1)
            && position > min && items.get(position - 1).equals(target)));
}
```

**BooleanExpression wrappers revisited**
note that the method parameters must be declared final
for this complex case the verbosity is defendable IMO
Maybe closures will make this easier, if they ever agree on that (-

```
private boolean targetFound5(final String target, final List<String> items,
        final int position, final int min, final int max) {

    abstract class BooleanExpression {
        abstract boolean eval();
    }

    BooleanExpression foundInWindow = new BooleanExpression() {

        boolean eval() {
            return position >= min && position < max
                    && (foundAtEvenPosition() || foundAtOddPosition());
        }

        private boolean foundAtEvenPosition() {
            return position % 2 == 0 && items.get(position).equals(target);
        }

        private boolean foundAtOddPosition() {
            return position % 2 == 1 && position > min
                    && items.get(position - 1).equals(target);
        }
    };

    BooleanExpression foundBefore = new BooleanExpression() {
        boolean eval() {
            return position < min && items.get(0).equals(target);
        }
    };

    BooleanExpression foundAfter = new BooleanExpression() {
        boolean eval() {
            return position >= max
                    && items.get(items.size() - 1).equals(target);
        }
    };

    return foundInWindow.eval() || foundBefore.eval() || foundAfter.eval();
}
```

I guess it really depends on the situation (as always). For very complex conditions the wrapper approach might be defendable, although it is uncommon.

Thanks for all your input!

EDIT: afterthought. It might be even better to create a specific class for complex logic such as this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class IsTargetFoundExpression {

    private final String target;
    private final List<String> items;
    private final int position;
    private final int min;
    private final int max;

    public IsTargetFoundExpression(String target, List<String> items, int position, int min, int max) {
        this.target = target;
        this.items = new ArrayList(items);
        this.position = position;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public boolean evaluate() {
        return foundInWindow() || foundBefore() || foundAfter();
    }

    private boolean foundInWindow() {
        return position >= min && position < max && (foundAtEvenPosition() || foundAtOddPosition());
    }

    private boolean foundAtEvenPosition() {
        return position % 2 == 0 && items.get(position).equals(target);
    }

    private boolean foundAtOddPosition() {
        return position % 2 == 1 && position > min && items.get(position - 1).equals(target);
    }

    private boolean foundBefore() {
        return position < min && items.get(0).equals(target);
    }

    private boolean foundAfter() {
        return position >= max && items.get(items.size() - 1).equals(target);
    }
}
```

The logic is complex enough to warrant a separate class (and unit test, yay!). It will keep the code using this logic more readable and promotes reuse in case this logic is needed elsewhere. I think this is a nice class because it truely has a single responsibility and only final fields.

Comment: I like your first solution, however with proper naming of variables, it may not be necessary.  Your second solution is too verbose IMO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find linebreaks and whitespace do a pretty good job, actually:

```
public static void main1(String[] args) {

    if (args != null
        && args.length == 2
        && !args[0].equals(args[1])
        ) {
            System.out.println("Args are ok");
    }
}
```

Admittedly it works better with my (unpopular) bracing style (not shown above), but even with the above it works fine if you put the closing paren and opening brace on their own line (so they're not lost at the end of the last condition).

I sometimes even comment the individual bits:

```
public static void main1(String[] args) {

    if (args != null                // Must have args
        && args.length == 2         // Two of them, to be precise
        && !args[0].equals(args[1]) // And they can't be the same
        ) {
            System.out.println("Args are ok");
    }
}
```

If you really want to call things out, multiple `if`s will do it:

```
public static void main1(String[] args) {

    if (args != null) {
        if (args.length == 2) {
            if (!args[0].equals(args[1])) {
                System.out.println("Args are ok");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...and any optimising compiler will collapse that. For me, it's probably a bit too verbose, though.

Comment: Multiple if is the most natural and most clear solution. It shows exactly what is going on. You can add comments on each line, too. But why would you need optimizing compiler? There is nothing to collapse.

Comment: The comments on each line have the added advantage of the Eclipse formatter not changing the line breaks.

Comment: Deep nesting is in most circumstances considered bad practice. I am however not sure if this particular case is an exception. It however indeed do improve readability.

Comment: @BalusC: Yeah, that's why I called it too verbose. @PauliL: Fair point, it probably doesn't need one.

Comment: Just adding linebreaks gets undone by the code formatter in Eclipse (ctrl+shift+f). Comments within the condition helps, but leaves little space for the logic. Multiple if's is a reasonable idea, although the deep nesting is not my favorite for readbility.

Comment: I *hate* when code formatters mess up the readability of my code. :-) I only use on-the-fly formatters, and try to customize them when I can.

Answer (score 13):

You can use early returns (from a method) to achieve the same effect:

[Some fixes applied]

```
  public static boolean areArgsOk(String[] args) {
     if(args == null)
        return false;

     if(args.length != 2)
        return false;

     if(args[0].equals(args[1]))
        return false;

     return true;
  }

  public static void main2(String[] args) {

        boolean b = areArgsOk(args);
        if(b)
           System.out.println("Args are ok");
  }
```

Comment: You forgot to pass in the args to areArgsOk().

Comment: Attention! He has &&-conditions.
Use
if(args == null) return false; if(args.length != 2)  return false; if(args[0].equals(args[1])) return false;
return true;

Comment: To improve readability use the method call in the if, don't assign it into a variable. "If(B)" isn't good for readability.

Answer (score 6):

If your goal is readability, why not simply break the lines and add comments?

```
    if (args != null                // args not null
        && args.length == 2         // args length is OK
        && !args[0].equals(args[1]) // args are not equal
    ) {

        System.out.println("Args are ok");
    }
```

Comment: For more complex conditions is better to extract each condition as a method, using each comment as a basis for naming those methods.

Answer (score 2):

The BooleanExpression type doesn't seem to be useful enough to be a class on its own outside your main class and it adds some intellectual weight to your application too.  I would simply just write private methods that are named appropriately to run the checks you want.  It's much simpler.

Comment: I think creating private methods is still too intrusive (and requires passing a lot of parameters). BooleanExpression lives within the method scope, so I can split up my condition without cluttering my top level class.

Comment: I disagree.  Using private methods is a lot easier to understand for anyone than embedding a class into a method.  Actually, the way BooleanExpression is defined, you might as well just use private methods.  Not only that, but because they are private, they can be changed later.

If this were a language like Groovy or Python, then I would say pass in a method (or closure) to handle validation.  Since it isn't, it's best to keep things simple (people who have to support this down the line will thank you for it).  The BooleanExpression is an attempt to mimic closures (or method parameters).

Answer (score 2):

You must do the variable assignment *INSIDE* the if's.

```
if (a && b && c) ...
```

translates to

```
calculatedA = a;
if (calculatedA) {
  calculatedB = b;
  if (calculatedB) {
    calculatedC = c;
    if (calculatedC) ....
  }
}
```

It is often beneficial to do this anyway since it names the concepts you are testing for, as you demonstrate clearly in your example code.  This increases readability.

Answer (score 2):

Your first solution is good for this kind of complexity. If the conditions were more complex, I would write private methods for each check you need to run. Something like:

```
public class DemoStackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    if ( areValid(args) ) {
        System.out.println("Arguments OK");
    }
    }

    /**
     * Validation of parameters.
     * 
     * @param args an array with the parameters to validate.
     * @return true if the arguments are not null, the quantity of arguments match 
     * the expected quantity and the first and second are not equal; 
     *         false, otherwise.
     */
    private static boolean areValid(String[] args) {
       return notNull(args) && lengthOK(args) && areDifferent(args);
    }

    private static boolean notNull(String[] args) {
       return args != null;
    }

    private static boolean lengthOK(String[] args) {
       return args.length == EXPECTED_ARGS;
    }

    private static boolean areDifferent(String[] args) {
       return !args[0].equals(args[1]);
    }

    /** Quantity of expected arguments */
    private static final int EXPECTED_ARGS = 2;

}
```

Comment: This is an illustration of my suggested answer.  +1

Answer (score 1):

This question is from 2009 but in the future (Java 8) we will be able to use Lambda expressions that may be for this context just like boolean expressions but you can use it so they are only evaluated when needed.

```
public static void main2(String[] args) {

    Callable<Boolean> argsNotNull = () -> args != null;
    Callable<Boolean> argsLengthOk = () -> args.length == 2;
    Callable<Boolean> argsAreNotEqual = () -> !args[0].equals(args[1]);

    if (argsNotNull.call() && argsLengthOk.call() && argsAreNotEqual.call()) {
        System.out.println("Args are ok");
    }
}
```

You can do the same with java 5/6 but it is less efficient and much more ulgy to write with anonymous classes.

Answer (score 0):

Split it out into a separate function (to improve readability in main()) and add a comment (so people understand what you are trying to accomplish)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (argumentsAreValid(args)) {
            System.out.println("Args are ok");
    }
}


public static boolean argumentsAreValid(String[] args) {
    // Must have 2 arguments (and the second can't be the same as the first)
    return args == null || args.length == 2 || !args[0].equals(args[1]);
}
```

ETA: I also like Itay's idea of using early returns in the ArgumentsAreValid function to improve the readability.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I don't really see how extracting a method this way improves things. Adding a comment is useful. Oh yes, 'bool' should be boolean and method names start with lowercase in Java.

Comment: @Adriaan - fixed the code there - getting too familiar with C# now and fogetting my Java.  Personally, I think splitting it out makes it more readable, but that is certainly a subjective judgement.

Answer (score 0):

Some good solutions already, but here's my variation. I usually do the null check as the topmost guard clause in all (relevant) methods. If I do it in this case, it leaves only the length and equality check in the subsequent if, which could already be considered a sufficient reduction in complexity and/or improvement in readability?

```
    public static void main1(String[] args) {

        if (args == null) return;

        if (args.length == 2 && !args[0].equals(args[1])) {
            System.out.println("Args are ok");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pragmatic, but not sufficient for the complex case I think.

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution won't work in many cases, including the example you give above. If args is null, then

```
boolean argsNotNull = args != null;
// argsNotNull==false, okay
boolean argsLengthOk = args.length == 2;
// blam! null pointer exception
```

One advantage of short-circuiting is that it saves on runtime. Another advantage is that it allows you to have early tests that check for conditions that would result in later tests throwing exceptions.

Personally, when the tests are individually simple and all that's making it complex is that there are many of them, I'd vote for the simple "add some line breaks and comments" solution. This is easier to read than creating a bunch of additional functions.

The only time I break things into subroutines is when an individual test is complex. If you need to go out and read a database or perform a big computation, then sure, roll that into a subroutine so the top level code is an easy-to-read

```
if (salesType=='A' && isValidCustomerForSalesTypeA(customerid))
etc
```

Edit:
How I'd break up the more complex example you gave.

When I really get conditions that are this complex, I try to break them up into nested IFs to make them more readable. Like ... and excuse me if the following isn't really equivalent to your example, I didn't want to study the parentheses too closely just for an example like this (and of course the parentheses are what makes it difficult to read):

```
if (position < min)
{
  return (items.get(0).equals(target));
}
else if (position >= max)
{
  return (items.get(items.size() - 1).equals(target));
}
else // position >=min && < max
{
  if (position % 2 == 0)
  {
    return items.get(position).equals(target);
  }
  else // position % 2 == 1
  {
     return position > min && items.get(position - 1).equals(target);
  }
}
```

That seems as readable to me as it's likely to get. In this example, the "top level" condition is clearly the relationship of position to min and max, so breaking that out really helps to clarify things, in my opinion.

Actually, the above is probably more efficient than cramming it all on one line, because the else's allow you to reduce the number of comparisons.

Personally I struggle with when it's a good idea to put a complex condition into a single line. But even if you understand it, the odds are that the next person coming along won't. Even some fairly straightforward things, like

return s==null ? -1 : s.length();

I sometimes tell myself, yeah, I get it, but others won't, maybe better to write

```
  if (s==null)
    return -1;
  else
    return s.length();
```

Comment: The first solution breaks short-circuiting, that was kind of my point. I am not considering big computations or reading from a database here, just a complex condition given that all the data is present.

Comment: @Adriaan: Okay. I was under the impression that you thought it was just an efficiency thing, and not a "doesn't work" thing. Well, I think my answer is correct, even if you already knew it!

Comment: Ok, so how would you present the more complex example condition I added at the top?

Comment: Fair enough. You optimized the condition a bit (all valid simplifications given the example), which makes it doable to present it in nested ifs. At some point however, conditions can get so complex that this becomes hard to keep readable. Anyway, I think I've stretched the subject long enough now. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Absolutely. It's a good discussion. If you or someone else reading this was hoping to get a simple, universally true and easy answer, I don't think there is one. Rather, like many things in the real world, it's a matter of general principles to apply as best you can in each situation. We could speculate that future computer languages might offer better solutions -- just like modern languages provision of "AND" and "OR" operators is a giant leap forward over what you had to write in assembly language. But I'm not aware of anything better than what's been discussed here.

Answer (score -1):

There's really nothing wrong with the first piece of code; you're overthinking things, IMO.

Here's another way that, while verbose, is easy to understand.

```
static void usage() {
    System.err.println("Usage: blah blah blah blah");
    System.exit(-1);
}

// ...

if (args == null || args.length < 2)
    usage();
if (args[0].equals(args[1]))
    usage()
```

Comment: Though it doesn't do quite the same thing in the presence of a security manager.

Comment: My example was simple for brevity. Consider a really complex condition. The above split up in two conditional statements seems arbitrary to me.

Comment: Yes, of course it's arbitrary! You write code for people to read, so you make judgments about what's clearest.