# Multiple return statement in java

Tags: java

```
private void test() {           
        // Nested if block 
        if (true) { // If condition is true
            if (true) { // If condition is true
                if (true) { // If condition is true
                    if (true) { // If condition is true
                         // statement
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Above block breaking in below way
        // Breaking nested if in multiple with return statement
        if (false) { // If condition is false
            return;
        }

        if (false) { // If condition is false
            return;
        }

        if (false) { // If condition is false
            return;
        }

        if (false) { // If condition is false
           return;
        }
    }
```

OOPs suggest multiple return statement is bad idea. But if I used multiple nested if then its look very complex.
Please suggest what is best way to use nested if condition

Comment: Take a look at [if-else-trees-vs-solid-principles](https://blog.mjouan.fr/if-else-trees-vs-solid-principles/)

Comment: When you nest too many if statements, that's usually a pretty clear sign that your function is doing too much. Try refactoring your method into smaller parts (methods) which each have their own specific functionality.

Comment: "OOPs suggest multiple return statement is bad idea." I find that's overhyped dogma, personally. It *can* be an indicator of a method doing too much, but it's often the simplest way of writing a method which *isn't* doing too much.

Comment: If your method is potentially expensive to execute, it's helpful to `return` early, when a part of your validation fails. So doing `if(false){return;}` might increase the performance of your code when done at the earliest possible point in the method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is better ? Multiple if statements, or one if with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259938/what-is-better-multiple-if-statements-or-one-if-with-multiple-conditions)

Comment: I think it's functional programming which suggests multiple returns is a bad idea, not sure OOP does.

Answer (score 6):

Multiple `return` statements is not good or bad in itself.
Early return and fail fast principle are not bad ways of coding and yet they rely on multiple `return` statements.
A single thing matters : the consistence and the code readability.

Your second way uses the "early return" pattern :

```
if (false) { // If condition is false
    return;
}

if (false) { // If condition is false
    return;
}

if (false) { // If condition is false
    return;
}

if (false) { // If condition is false
   return;
}
```

Now nothing prevents you from improving this code by removing the duplication :
 `if (...) returns ...;`. 
Abusing of these can indeed finish to produce a less readable code because too noises and scattered rules.

Your example is really too abstract to provide a specific answer.
So, suppose that multiple of your conditional statements rely on a object of a specific class to be evaluated.

In this case, you could store conditional statements in a List and iterate on it to apply each rule. As soon as one is not valid, you exit.

```
List<Predicate<MyObject>> predicates = Arrays.asList(MyObject::isValid, 
                                                    (m)-> m.getColor()==BLUE);
```

And now apply rules :

```
MyObject myObj = ...;
for (Predicate<MyObject> predicate : predicates) {
    if (!predicate.test(myObj)) {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Understand that no rules are cast in stone. (Software) engineering is always about *balancing* different requirements/rules.

In your case: option 2, using multiple return statements is **clearly** much easier to comprehend for human readers.

In that sense: go for that. As this solution also works much better in regards of the *[single layer of abstraction](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:single_level_of_abstraction)* principle!

But I also agree with the comments - a lengthy sequence of if/else checks is most often a symptom of insufficient design. One doesn't need to completely abandon `if`s (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264145/if-less-programming-basically-without-conditionals)) - but assuming that your main concern is to improve the quality of your current code you should rather invest your time looking into that question *why are there so many if statements in that method*.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
if (condition || condition || condition)
    return;
```

or either

```
if (condition && condition && condition) {
    statement's
}
```

obviously each condition may be on its own line It just depends on the conditions, what exactly is being done, ... and somehow also on what you want to 'express'.