# Is it safe to pass a function as the second condition of an IF when I want it to be called only when the first condition is true?

Tags: php

I'm calling a function to insert some thing in SQL, and I wanted to know if is it safe to have the function as second condition to an if statement, and if it would be called only when the first condition is true, and I would like to know if it would be good pratice too;

I know I could include another if inside that if, and it would work fine, but I'm trying not to include too many unnecessary if statements.
It isn't the same as wanting to know if it's better to use nested IFs, because what I wanted to know was if the function would be called when the first condition evaluated to false or not.

```php
if (empty($err) && InsertSQL($args)) {
 echo "success";
} else {
 $err .= "fail to insert";
}

echo $err;
```

I expect it to output success if there is no error in $err and the function returns true, and "fail to insert" and the other error if there is an error or if there is no error but the function returns false, I'll just get "fail to insert"

Comment: Yes, however you just get `fail` and don't know or state why it failed of the 2 conditions.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: I know, but I have code somewhere else that outputs me the errors.
I changed the code in the question a bit to show it better, If I got an error before the IF statement, I get both errors, if only the insert failed, I get the insert error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is better ? Multiple if statements, or one if with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259938/what-is-better-multiple-if-statements-or-one-if-with-multiple-conditions)

Comment: Just bear in mind that if you have an expression such as `true && func()`, `func()` is called whatever its return.

Comment: @Progrock Thanks! That's what I intended: If the function returns true, SQL will be inserted, but if it fails it returns false and I don't get a success message, but an error message telling me it had failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the && short-circuits. So, if the first condition fails it doesn't bother evaluating the second condition. So, the `InsertSQL()` function would not be called.